# Specifying function argument names in lua

Tags: lua

I load the body of a function from a string (with C api), but by default, all arguments passed to the function are accessed with `...`. What is the best way to specify an argument list? I can only think of prepending a line like the following to the string before parsing it (assume the arguments should be self, x, y):

```
local self, x, y = ...
```

However, I'm not sure if its the best way to do this, or whether it has any unintended side effects.

Update: in one of the functions, I need an argument list of the form `self, type, ...`. The following wouldn't work, right?

```
local self, type, ... = ...
```

Should I use this instead?

```
text = "return function(self, type, ...)" + text + " end";
luaL_loadbufferx(L, text, text.length(), filename, "t");
lua_call(L, 0, 1);
```

Comment: Your last solution is good. Just note that you need to call lua_call *twice* to run your code.

Comment: Yes, after the fragment I posted I grab the function from the stack and store it for later use. First solution has no lua_call.

Answer (score 3):

Prepending that line is an excellent way to create named arguments. If you use a local declaration as you have, then there won't be any side effects (except the ones from the rest of the code).

Comment: Okay, great, though if for some reason my arguments needs to be (self, ...) - I can't do that, right?

Comment: You can eliminate the (self) from the arguments by using this: `function Thing:functionName()` (the :() is the same as saying self)